# All Pages Redirecting To Frontpage

Tags: updating, .htaccess

I am hoping that someone could assist me with a Pressflow problem on here as i cant find anywhere at all to discuss Pressflow. I have just updated my site to the latest version of Pressflow which was updated with the recent Drupal update. I uploaded all the files and now i can only access the frontpage of my site.

http://onlinebanter.com

If you try to click any links it just displays the front page. Would it be something to do with the htaccess file possibly?

All help appreciated as my site is effectively down with this problem and i dont know where to turn nor have the technical know how.

Thanks

Comment: Solved - it was the htaccess file

Comment: Hi Reg, you should answer it yourself and mark it correct so other users can find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Malks. Yip it was the htaccess file i overwrote folks. I just edited that again with my website url in 2 spots and everything was hunky dory again.